# ActiveRecord Versioning plugin/gem compatible with rails3?

Tags: activerecord, versioning, ruby-on-rails-3

I googled for the the plugin/gem to do the ActiveRecord versioning for Rails3.

But all I've got is not compatible for Rails3. I even searched in RailsPlugins.org too, but no luck.

Do you know any that is Rails3 ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also http://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Answer (score 1):

The acts_as_versioned gem seems to not officially support rails3 yet, but [this guy](http://rhaamo.li/rails3/2010/06/12/using-acts-as-versioned-with-rails3.html) has forked the project and created a rails3 branch. Take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I think I will go the way of `vestal_versions` gem.